# Compiling code with .d extension using rebuild and drebuild?

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, d, rebuild

I wanted to build [AsciiAsciiRevolution](https://github.com/osgcc/osgcc4-AsciiAsciiRevolution) so I checked it out and typed `make`

```
$ make
rebuild AAR.d -oqobj -I~/tango/ -Iycurses/modules -L-lncursesw -dc=ldc-posix-tango -version=Tango
/bin/sh: 1: rebuild: not found
```

Huh? What's rebuild?

```
$ ls
AAR.d                  asciiSprite.d   graphics       levels.txt  README          util
animatedAsciiSprite.d  backupDancer.d  input.d        Makefile    selectScreen.d  warningBar.d
arrow_charts           dancingMan.d    level.d        music       sounds          ycurses
arrowSection.d         dataScore.d     levelScreen.d  narwhal.d   types.d
```

What the... is this that mysterious [D Language](http://dlang.org/) I've heard about?

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
    rebuild AAR.d -oqobj -I~/tango/ -Iycurses/modules -L-lncursesw -dc=ldc-posix-tango -version=Tango

james:
    drebuild AAR.d -oqobj -I/usr/include/d/ldc -Iycurses/modules -L-lncursesw -dc=ldc-posix-tango -version=Tango -I~/repos/tango

clean:
    rm AAR obj/*.o
```

Okay, I just have to install `rebuild` and `drebuild`!

```
$ sudo apt-get install rebuild drebuild
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rebuild
```

At this point I tried `apt-cache search rebuild`, but nothing there seemed related to `dlang`. What is `rebuild`, and how can I install it using `apt-get` or `yum`?

Answer (score 3):

`rebuild` is a rather old build tool for D. It is part of DSSS (D Shared Source System), which was an early attempt at a D package manager. You can find more information on the project's page on Dsource: http://www.dsource.org/projects/dsss

These tools have not been maintained for a long time and today are rarely used. They have been replaced by `rdmd` (included with the compiler) for the build tool, and [dub](http://code.dlang.org/) as the package manager.

Comment: So it sounds like I'm not going to `apt-get` my way out of this one and I'll just have to download and install it manually.

Comment: Yep, I don't think those tools were packaged for any distribution.

Answer (score 3):

To add to CyberShadow's response.

That code was developed with a very old tool chain, specifically it uses D v1 with [Tango](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango). Luckily it likely means that with those properly installed, building should work.

If you were to download v2 there would be work to update everything, which wouldn't be simple if you're not already familiar with the language and its tooling.